# A more intuitive formulation of time-dependent Schrödinger equation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, complex-numbers

Is there an intuitive reason why the time-dependent Schrödinger equation is formulated as:

$i{\hbar}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{dt}}\Psi=H\Psi$

and is that the most intuitive way to look at it?  Or are there more intuitive ways to write it and understand it?

The above formulation seems like gobbledygook to me.  But today I looked at it and realized that it might make a lot more sense for me if it was written as:

$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{dt}}\Psi=-2\pi i\frac{H}{h}\Psi$

Then I would explain it as follows.

Suppose that we are studying a system, and for specificity and simplicity, that it is a periodic system, namely, a harmonic oscillator, like an ideal spring in one-dimension $x$ with momentum $p$.  Suppose that the spring moves between $x_{max}$ and $-x_{max}$ and at $x=0$ achieves its extreme momentums, $p_{max}$ and $-p_{max}$.  And let that system have a certain amount of slack. This slack may be thought of as error bounds for measurements, or as a multitude of systems that we are choosing from, or as a looseness in the laws of nature so that momentum can transform into position and vice versa.

Position will be best defined ($|x|< \epsilon_{small}$) near $x=0$, at which time momentum may vary the most ($||p|-|p_{max}||< \epsilon_{large}$). And momentum will be best defined ($|p|< \epsilon_{small}$) when the system has extreme position ($||x|-|x_{max}||< \epsilon_{large}$). Overall, the total slack can be thought of as the product $\epsilon_{small}\epsilon_{large}$, a rectangle in phase space. I suppose that rectangle is an oriented area in that it circles around phase space $(x,p)$ in one-direction, counterclockwise, and not clockwise. And I think this oriented area is conserved, although I can't prove that. And I guess that this is perhaps the simplest example of symplectic geometry, which I imagine is the study of the geometry of such slack in the form of oriented areas.

Suppose the wave function $\Psi=0$ outside the rectangle and nonzero within the rectangle. Then the wave function $\Psi$ is describing the location of that rectangle in phase space. And $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{dt}}\Psi$ is describing the rate of change in that location over time.

Then my formulation explains all that is involved. The factor $i$ means that the slack exists only because position and momentum are kept track of separately, where, say, momentum is multiplied by $i$. Without it, the the system would be rigid and there could be no conversion between kinetic energy (which is maximum at the extreme of momentum) and potential energy (which is maximum at the extreme of position). Multiplying by $i$ means that slack in position arises from the value of the momentum, and slack in momentum arises from the value of the position. Note that if the rectangle was not moving, then 
$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{dt}}\Psi=0$ and the probability $\Psi$ is constant, which is to say that our rectangle is unbounded.

The factor $-1$ simply arises from our choice of axes for position and momentum. When position becomes positive, momentum shrinks and grows negative. I think if we swapped the axes, then the factor would go away.

The factor $2\pi$ perhaps arises in our unit of time, in that we are thinking in terms of an entire cycle of periodic activity in phase space. I imagine that the crucial thing here is that the exponential $e^{2\pi i x}$ is the limit of $(1 + ix\frac{2\pi}{n})^n$ whose multiplicative effect is simply to linearly add the rotations that take us around the circle an amount $x$.

Finally, in my formulation, we come to the crucial factor, which is the fraction $\frac{H}{h}$. Note that this has units $\frac{1}{t}$ and thus is a frequency. Suppose $h$ is fixed. Then the higher the energy $H$, then the greater the change in slack, which here means, the more rapid oscillation between extremes in momentum and position. I suppose for that to hold in a well defined periodic system, as above, then the fraction $\frac{H}{h}$ is forced to be an integer.

If $\Psi$ is a real valued probability function on the phase space, then the amount of slack never changes, but is simply transfered from position to momentum and vice versa.  However, if $\Psi$ has a complex component of probability, then I suppose that as this component is multiplied by $i$,  $\Psi$ smears out by a factor of $e^\frac{H}{\hbar}$. I suppose that is related to the problem in my (mis)understanding. Also, I am treating the Hamiltonian as a constant, when it is an operator, although in the simplest case, couldn't it act as a multiplicative constant?

Please, to what extent is my explanation reasonable or wrong? And how might I better understand the time-dependent Schrödinger equation, if possible, with regard to the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how you slice it, quantum mechanics is counter-intuitive. On a microscopic level, the world does not behave like everyday experience leads us to expect. So while you have put some effort and thought into this, I don't think it will help. Moving the constants makes no difference to most physicists. It is a small change and the equation stays essentially the the same.

The real problem is that you have some misconceptions based on everyday experience. You expect a harmonic oscillator to have a trajectory with $x_{min}$, $x_{min}$, $p_{max}$, and $p_{max}$ that repeats periodically. This is not the case.

There is no trajectory. You cannot say where a particle is at any given time. Not even theoretically if you knew more about the particle than you can see. For example, you might expect if only you knew the initial position and momentum, then you would know where the particle is later. There is no exact initial position and momentum, nor exact values at any later time. Likewise, there is no definite limit on how big $x$ or $p$ will get for a harmonic oscillator.

---

Like in classical mechanics, forces can constrain the location and momentum of a particle. The Earth orbits the Sun, never getting too far away.

Energy is useful for thinking about classical mechanics. With forces, you need to know the position and momentum now to predict position and momentum later. With energy, you do not. Given the force of attraction between Sun and Earth, you can calculate the potential energy at any position. The total energy is constant. If Earth gets too from the Sun it gain potential energy and loses kinetic energy. The farthest away the Earth can get is a position where the kinetic energy is $0$.

Some of these ideas carry over into quantum mechanics. The typical example is a hydrogen atom, where an electron is attracted to a proton. A proton is big enough that it can be treated classically. For each position, you can calculate the potential energy an electron would have if it was at that position.

But an electron is never at a particular position or momentum. $\Psi$ is a function from which you can calculate probable locations and momenta of the electron. You must use all the probable locations now to calculate the distribution of future probable locations and momenta.

The Schrodinger equation tells you how to do that. But you don't deal directly with position and momenta. $H$ is defined by the potential energy at each position. You use $H$ and a starting $\Psi$ to calculate a future $\Psi$.

A typical hydrogen atom has a definite energy and doesn't change. $\frac{d}{dt}\Psi =0$. You can use this to calculate the $\Psi$ that describes the ground state of hydrogen. From $\Psi$, you can calculate the unchanging distribution of probable locations of the electron. But you can't find out anything about which location it occupies now, or which it will occupy next. You can also calculate the unchanging distribution of momenta.

One of the counter-intuitive things from quantum mechanics is that the total energy of the ground state is not $0$. The electron has a non-$0$ distribution of momenta. And yet the distribution of positions does not change. It is a mistake to think that the electron really has some unknowable position and that position is changing. All it has is distributions of probable positions and momenta. To find out anything about the electron, you do a calculation that integrates over $\Psi$ at all positions. If you cannot learn about a property of the electron from such a calculation, the electron does not have that property. You cannot learn the position of the electron because the electron does not have a position.

---

You can do something similar for a 1 dimensional harmonic oscillator. The potential is 
not rectangular as you described. It is of the form $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$.

Again, you can calculate a ground state where $\Psi$ does not change. You can also calculate excited states where $\Psi$ is a periodic function of time. For these, even though you cannot say where the particle is at a given time, the most likely region for it to be does move periodically.

Comment: Thank you @mmesser314 for your long answer.  You write a lot about quantum mechanics in general.  I am specifically trying to understand the meaning of the various terms in the Schroedinger equation and how they come together.  I am seeking an answer that would help me make sense of that.  I suppose that I need to just read more about wave functions and about derivatives of complex functions.  Also, I should modify my example so that $\Psi$ is differentiable.